# JSF rich:scrollableDataTable rowcount on javascript popop

Tags: javascript, jsf

I use javascript confirmation pop-up for one of the rich faces command button functionalities. On the same page, I also have a `rich:scrollableDataTable`. Is it possible for me to show the number of data rows in the table on the java script confirmation pop-up? If yes, how can i achieve that?

Thanks in advance - Avinash.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
var count = $("#yourTableId tbody tr").length;
```

and then pass it to the pop-up.

Comment: I'd however put a `tbody` in between to avoid that header/footer rows are included.